# Method to declare a known number of variables with numerically sequenced names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

How can I declare a known number of variables with numerically sequenced names using a loop in sql server 2014. Like var_1, var_2 etc.?

Comment: XY - You should explain why you want to do this (because you should never need to do this)

Comment: This also sounds alot like homework. We can help, but you need to explain why you want to do what you are doing and what your desired output is.

Comment: Sql uses rows for this. If you want another variable, you create a new row instead

Comment: I am trying to create a function that chooses n parameters from a table and for each n, chooses k column names from another table. it finally has to create a table with some fixed columns + n*k columns which change with input parameters. k is also different for each n. I figured I could run a cursor or while loop to fetch each n and feed the corresponding column names into a table variable. declaring the variables and setting their values inside the loop felt like the efficient way to go. finally I'll pivot the variables and join them to form the required table.

Comment: The approach maybe crude, it is my first attempt at such a task. all suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic Query..

> declare @i as int
>   set @i=10
>   print @i
>
> while (@i>0)
>   begin
>   print 'Declare @var_'+cast(@i as varchar(2))+' as YOUR Datatype'
>   set @i=@i-1
>   end

Comment: doesn't work for me. I need to actually declare and then assign these variables in loop, not just print these statements.